# Firefox global application menu in Classic Desktop?

Tags: firefox, gnome-panel, globalmenu, gnome2, gnome-classic

I am using Natty without unity, but I am a fan of the global menu applet. Unfortunately, it does not work for Firefox 5 (and other programs that draw them themselves).

How can I activate the special globalmenus for the non-unity globalmenu app (or: is it possible)?

Comment: Make you sure you have `firefox-globalmenu` package installed.

Comment: I've ensured it.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score -3):

make sure you have firefox-globalmenu installed AND disable firefox's new menu that appears folded at the top left corner of firefox's main window.
HERE http://mozcom-cdn.mozilla.net/img/covehead/features/screen-firefoxbutton-linux.png is a screenshot of the menu i'm talking about

Comment: Some instructions on how to go about disabling the new menu would improve this answer.